# what is internal protection, and why does strange class work?

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine, abstract-class, internal

If I make BaseClass public it starts complaining:

```
Assets/TestScript.cs(14,14): error CS0060: Inconsistent accessibility: base class `Class1' is less accessible than class `BaseClass'
```

First I don't understand why is it complaining as afaik base class should be the one from where you start accessing stuff

B cannot access protected functions witch is fine.

but what are the internal classes?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {
    BaseClass B = new BaseClass();
    Class2 A = new BaseClass(); // how can this even work and why does it work?
Class2 C = new Class2(); // Assets/TestScript.cs(7,28): error CS0144: Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface `Class2' // - WTH why?
    void Start(){
        B.BaseFunction(); // Base
        B.Function1(); // Assets/TestScript.cs(10,19): error CS0122: `Class1.Function1()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
        A.Function2(); // 2
    }
}

internal class BaseClass : Class1 {
    internal void BaseFunction(){
        Debug.Log("Base");
    }
}
internal abstract class Class1 : Class2{
    protected void Function1(){
        Debug.Log("1");
    }
}
public abstract class Class2{
    public void Function2(){
        Debug.Log("2");
    }
}
```

or did I just make bunch of stuff that works same as public does?

but ATM what bugges me the most is why does this work:

```
Class2 A = new BaseClass();
```

if this doesn't work

```
Class2 C = new Class2();
```

Sorry if I'm too little knowledgeable about classes I just started learning them today after 1 year of programming.

Answer (score 3):

You have everything named very badly... it makes it confusing. If you make `BaseClass` *actually be* a base class.. then it should make more sense:

```
public abstract class AbstractBase {
    public void BaseFunction(){
        Debug.Log("2");
    }
}

public class Class1 : AbstractBase {
    public void ClassOneFunction(){
        Debug.Log("Base");
    }
}
public abstract class Class2 : Class1 {
    public void ClassTwoFunction(){
        Debug.Log("1");
    }
}
```

Now if we re-work your issues, you get something like this:

```
AbstractBase A = new Class1();
```

You are representing an instance of `Class1` as an `AbstractBase` which is totally fine. You can substitute anything that inherits from `AbstractBase` in place of an `AbstractBase` declaration. This is *polymorphism* at work.

The key thing to remember here is that when you represent an instance of `Class1` as an `AbstractBase`.. it is only "visible" as an `AbstractBase`. So, given the above code.. this won't work:

```
AbstractBase A = new Class1();
A.ClassOneFunction(); // won't work because Function2 is a function of Class1
```

The one that doesn't work:

```
Class2 C = new Class2();
```

..is because `Class2` in your code is `abstract`. You simply cannot instantiate instances of `abstract` classes. They are there to be inherited from.. not instantiated.

The *inconsistent accessibility* error is because `internal` is less accessible than `public`. If your method is `internal`.. then it isn't visible outside of the assembly.

Comment: @user3276642 No.. it wouldn't. Re-read the code. `AbstractBase` is _abstract_.. you cannot instantiate it.

Comment: yes I did that's why I deleted comment before you commented, ... I'm trying to get my head around this ATM but I think I'll need a big sleep before I'll understand it fully, ... it's 9:30 AM, ...

Comment: did I understood correctly, base class is where everything goes to not end of the line where something comes from?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. What I would suggest is that you revise your understanding of OO, abstract classes, interfaces and polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic difference between modifiers:

[this would help you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)
protected:

The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct, or in a derived class.

internal:

The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.

protected internal:

The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, or by any derived class in another assembly.

protected internal; only derived types or types within the same assembly can access that member, so they need to be in the same Dynamic Link Library or an executable file.

Comment: what is the same assembly?